# Where can I find a Unesco World Heritage List as boundaries?

Tags: vector, polygon, data

I was wondering if anyone knows where to find the UNESCO world heritage list with boundaries?  I can extract point data from the json feed for the map on the website http://whc.unesco.org/en/list via
 http://whc.unesco.org/?cid=31&l=en&mode=json but polygon or polyline data would be much more preferable.

Edit:  I was particularly interested in Australia, but it would be good to know where to go to find this sort of info worldwide, so if you have other countries, feel free to post them up as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:

There is the following site that I have just found:

http://www.protectedplanet.net/

They have downloads of protected areas for the world.

The help page tells you how you can download the data, which is available in shp, KMZ or CSV format:

http://www.protectedplanet.net/help

If you do a search for Australia, you can then filter your results for world heritage sites, and download this data as a shp.

---

I dont know about the rest of the world, but for the UK you can download a large amount of designation data from Magic:

[Magic](http://magic.defra.gov.uk/).

This will link you to the English Heritage page for the English boundaries:

[English Heritage](http://services.english-heritage.org.uk/NMRDataDownload/).

You will need to register to download the information.

For Scotland it is available from Scottish Natural Heritage:

[Scottish Natural Heritage](https://gateway.snh.gov.uk/pls/apex_ddtdb2/f?p=101:11:1185067710815645%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_AUTH_CAT,P11_DS_NAME,P11_DS_ID%3aNational%20Dataset,%5CScotland%20World%20Heritage%20Sites%20%28Natural%20Heritage%29%5C,10076)

I could not find any information on the Countryside Council for Wales website for Wales.

[CCW](http://www.ccw.gov.uk/landscape--wildlife/protecting-our-landscape/gis-download---welcome/gis-boundary-downloads.aspx)

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was after (and more)